# Human belief systems and reason

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Belief puts people into action, but often action is needed before *belief* to develop something in order to be able to believe in it in the first place, or at least so it seems.

It seems to me that many people like Gallileo and Archimedes didn't knew what they might find in their work, the question is how did they acted without belief or how did they develop the belief to be able to act despite so much uncertainty of what they might find being useful at all?

Often reason isn't able to change one's belief systems. It is the belief in the reason itself that might change one's beliefs. How to develop such belief in one's reason to be able to change your own beliefs just by logically reasoning without any interference of third parties -- just you yourself and your own pure thought alone?

What are your thoughts on this subject and are there any books, research papers, on this topic worth your recommendation?

Comment: I think you should be more specific about your definitions, because some of your terms mean different things to different people. In the Catholic philosophical tradition, for example, belief is defined as something like "the rational response to God/God's revelation/etc.", so the idea that "reason isn't able to change one's belief systems" is a contradiction. Other philosophical schools take "belief" as an incomplete form of knowledge, as in: I believe there is a cat in the box, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: It seems you should put the whole question in the **context** of philosophy of science, described by the tags, to avoid any further confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The famous mathematician and philosopher Blaise Pascal had a theory that belief follows action --if you act as a believer, you gain faith (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Wager --note the section marked "Inability to Believe").  It seems likely that he found this to be true in his own life --certainly theologically, and perhaps as a scientist as well.

As far as (other) scientists and innovators who have believed in their theories before the evidence arrived to confirm them --it seems fairly obvious that belief in unproven theories is common.  Those whose theories are later confirmed are celebrated as visionaries, those whose theories don't pan out are dismissed as cranks.  If there wasn't a certain base willingness among people to occasionally step out on faith, the ability of humanity to advance would be severely curtailed.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally recognized that you must have auxilliary (sometimes unquestioned) assumptions when building and testing a scientific hypothesis. They can take the form of metaphysical assumptions which act as regulative principles, or assumptions regarding the form of the law or the kind of explanation we are trying to find.
Examples are numerous but principles of causality (an explanation should take the form of a cause-effect relation), or reductionism can play this role in science, as well as a bunch of common sense assumptions such as: the hair colour of the experimenter or the position of jupiter should not affect a measurement on earth...
In sum, we never start from nowhere but have background assumptions which constrain the form of acceptable (and accessible) beliefs.